# override the opacity of parent view

Tags: titanium

I have view which has a button on it,
What I want to do is make the view transprent and not button.

At first I set opacity in both setting,

but myButton opacity is inherited by myView opacity setting.

```
var myView= Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : 'black',
    //  backgroundColor : rgba(0,0,0,0.5), // try1 
    //  backgroundColor : "#000000CC",  // try2
    opacity:0.8,
    zIndex:5
});

var myButton =  Titanium.UI.createButton({
    backgroundImage  : '/img/close.png',
    opacity: 1,
});
myView.add(myButton);
```

Then I googled around and found this [article](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/11/adding-transparent-background/).

And try to use of 'rgba' way, but in vain.

Is there any good workaround??

My titanium version is

Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 5.0.5, Titanium SDK version 5.1.1.GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an opacity to a parent, their childrens will have the opacity too. The trick is to add a second view before the button with the opacity like this :

```
var myView= Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : 'transparent'
});

myView.add(Ti.UI.createView({
    width : '100%',
    height : '100%'
    backgroundColor : 'black',
    opacity:0.8,
    touchEnabled : false
});

var myButton =  Titanium.UI.createButton({
    backgroundImage  : '/img/close.png'
});

myView.add(myButton);
```